# Get Facebook images based upon a description

Tags: php, facebook

I need to create a program which allows to store photos of which people has uploaded in Facebook based on the photo description. For example, I upload/post on Facebook a picture with the description "#awesomeevent" the program should be able to store this particular image into the database. Twitter has hashtags but Facebook do not any where which i can work around this ?

I was thinking of using a FQL query but unsure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The best (and only?) way to do this imho is to include the hashtag in the message of the photos and read it from there. I would not use FQL for that, because there is no need to use it. The Graph API offers enough possibilities/connections to read photos:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

(/me/photos, /me/photos/uploaded, /me/albums, ...)

Comment: however, how do i store the photos into a database or how to i use a graph api to retrieve the pics based on the hash tags.

Comment: if this is your first time with the graph api, then i suggest reading some tutorials and starting with the php sdk: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Comment: after that, see my answer. those are the graph api connections you will need. you can test what you will get back with the graph api explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
also don´t forget to read the facebook terms, it´s not allowed to store the private photos of a user without telling him exactly for how long and why...